# Proof Verification: Let $A$ be bounded above so that $s=$ sup $A$ exists. Prove that $s \in \overline{A}$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I have seen that this question has been answered already, but I wanted to come up with my own proof and would appreciate some feedback, as I am not always the best at transferring what is in my head into words and math symbology.

Proof: By definition, $\overline{A} = A \cup L$, where $L$ is the set of all limit points of $A$. In order for $s \in \overline{A}$, either $s \in A$ or $s \in L$.

Suppose $s \in A$. Then we are done, as $s \in A \Rightarrow s \in A \cup L \Rightarrow s \in \overline{A}$.

Now suppose that $s \notin A$. By definition, as $s=$ sup $A$, $s$ is the least upper bound of $A$. Let $V_\varepsilon(s)$ be an $\varepsilon$-neighborhood of $s$. Then no matter how small we make $\varepsilon$, $V_\varepsilon(s) \cap A \neq \emptyset$ since $s=$ sup $A$, which implies that $s \in L$. Then $s \in L \Rightarrow s\in A \cup L \Rightarrow s\in \overline{A}$.

Q.E.D.

Even if this proof is correct, I still don't feel great about the line where I write "Then, no matter how small we make $\varepsilon$..." I guess it just doesn't feel very mathy to me, and I am also not sure it transitions as well as it could from the idea that $s=$ sup $A$.

Comment: Your proof is quite 'mathy'!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think "no matter how small we make $\epsilon$" is how I would describe it if in conversation, but I can definitely get the desire to make it more 'mathy', particulary if it's for a graded assignment.

If you want to 'math it up a bit', my suggestion is that you spend a couple lines proving why $V_\epsilon(s)\cap A\neq\emptyset$ for all $\epsilon > 0$, possibly with a contradiction proof. For instance, if there is an $\epsilon >0$ such that $V_\epsilon(s)\cap A =\emptyset$, what can you say about some of the elements in this neighborhood and their relation to both $s$ and to all of the elements of $A$?

Comment: I see what you mean... so maybe something along the lines of "If $V_\varepsilon(s) \cap A = \emptyset$, this would imply that $s \neq$ sup $A$, as $V_\varepsilon(s)$ would contain elements less than $s$ that are not in $A$"?

Comment: Not only not in $A$, but larger than every element in $A$. Which has consequences for the status of $s$ being $\sup A$.